# where does racket lambda argument come from?

Tags: function, lambda, arguments, racket, programming-languages

**I asked a similar question before, I just want to make sure I understand the idea, in the -lambda(x)- line 4, what is the x, where it is coming from?**

```
(define (cached-assoc xs n)
  (letrec ([memo (make-vector n #f)]
           [acc 0]
           [f (lambda(x)
                (let ([ans (vector-assoc x memo)])
                  (if ans
                      (cdr ans)
                      (let ([new-ans (assoc x xs)])
                       (begin
                         (vector-set! memo acc (cons x new-ans))
                         (set! acc (if (= (+ acc 1)) 0 (+ acc 1)))
                         new-ans)))))])
  f))
```

Comment: If `f` is a function that takes one argument, `f` is equivalent to `(lambda (x) (f x))`. (Compare `(f 1)` and `((lambda (x) (f x)) 1)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cached-assoc` procedure returns `f`, a function which has `x` as an unbound parameter. It doesn’t have a value yet, the value will be whatever you pass to it when you finally invoke it:

```
((cached-assoc xs n) 10)
```

In the above example `x` will be bound to 10, and `xs` and `n` will be whatever you defined for them before calling `cached-assoc`. I believe the source of the confusion is the fact that `cached-assoc` is *returning a `lambda`*, once you understand this it'll be clear.